# Array in Powershell WON'T be written as an Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, dynamic-arrays

No matter how I write this script, Powershel will not write my array as it should, it prints a single line array.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $matriz = @(
(1,2,3,4),
(5,6,7,8)
)

Write-Host $matriz
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Neither this way:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $matriz = ,@((1,2,3,4),
(5,6,7,8))

Write-Host $matriz
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

How do I print this as a real 2-dimension matrix?
And... I'm trying to populate this same array with `Get-Random`, but it shows the following error: `Failed add the number where you want (i.e. matriz [0,1]) because it doesn't support fractions` <- Not the real message but you guys won't understand portuguese :/

*Update:
I want it to be printed as this:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
'Cause the single line thing won't help me to see if my matrix is correct, as a single line I will never know what is in the array's diagonal line.

Comment: What do you want as your desired output? Please Update your question with an example

Comment: @Matt It didnt worked out, and every tutorial I see the methods that I've posted works just fine... is it possible to be some kind of setting on my powershell? Using PS ISE, the PS "Prompt-Window" outputs as a single line too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So when you output an array, powershell by default outputs each array item on a new line. Here is one way to get what I think you want:

```
Write-Host $matriz | %{$_ -join ' '}
```

So you tell it to go ahead and use the new line for the outside array, but for each of the inside arrays join them using spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This uses a trick but will make it print in two lines:

```
$matriz = ,@(1,2,3,4)+,@(5,6,7,8)
$matriz | % {Write-Host $_ }
```

Output is:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Each item can be individually referenced as `$matriz[x][y]` where x,y are the sizes of the two dimentional array (As Bacon said).

Answer (score 0):

That is how a two dimensional array prints.  If you want to display it in some other way, you'll need to format it yourself:

```
$matriz  = @((1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8))

$matriz  | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | ForEach-Object {
        Write-Host ("{0,5}" -f $_) -NoNewline;
    }
    Write-Host;
}
```

You're also not calling matrix elements correctly.  `$matriz[1,1]`, for example, actually means `(,$matriz[1] + ,$matriz[1])`.  That's because `1,1` is itself an array.

What you'd need to do to properly find single elements is to use multiple indexes: `$matriz[1][1]`